# Find x in a sequence of Arithmetic Progression (AP)

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

If $(8x+1), (6x-1)$ and $(3x+5)$ are in an AP, find the value of $x$. This sum is from a question paper and there is no other information given. I was able to solve other sums which had more information available. But I'm stuck at this sum.

Comment: There is sufficient information, what have you tried so far? What do you know of arithmetic progressions?

Comment: Edit and include your efforts, please.

Comment: @Macavity The formulas I have been taught require either the first term of an AP or the difference or at least the sum/product of all terms in the AP. However, this is the only question that is different and I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Well, you have two ways to express the common difference from the information given, try it and edit the post above. if you still need help, i am sure you'll get it here.

Comment: Here is the solution: https://brainly.in/question/14434359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an A.P, $$a_2-a_1=a_3-a_2$$ Here $a_1=8x+1, a_2=6x-1, a_3=3x+5$ So,
$$(6x-1)-(8x+1) = (3x+5)-(6x-1)$$
$$\implies6x-1-8x-1=3x+5-6x+1$$
$$\implies-2x-2=-3x+6$$
$$\implies x=8$$
Therefore the value of $x$ is $8$

Hope it helps

Comment: Please take a look at [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508).

Comment: @Saad I apologize for posting a question with so few details, but I really had no other information available and could not infer more from the problem statement. This is not to say there is a problem with the sum, but a problem with my ability to solve math.

I will try my best to improve and add more information to my questions in the future

Comment: @Algebrology Thank you.

Comment: @NAPOLEON039 This time I answered your question but from next time please make sure that you also add what you have done to solve this problem :)

Comment: @NAPOLEON039 Welcome. Glad I could help :)